# How to run user scripts on Firefox's built-in PDF Viewer?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, pdf-viewer

I'm running a simple Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey user scrip in Firefox which gets selection of a text (let's say, just a single word) and opens a translator for it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     translator
// @version  1.0
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('dblclick', handleDblClick, true);

function handleDblClick(e) {
    var txt = window.getSelection().toString();
    window.open("https://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru&text=" + txt);
}
```

This works fine with ordinary web-pages, but not with built-in PDF Viewer. Is there any chance to make this (or any other) script running while viewing PDF-files in Firefox?

Here is a small sample of PDF-file to try with: http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf

Comment: Firefox 60 and newer decided to disallow scripts in its built-in PDF viewer: https://bugzil.la/1454760

Answer (score 2):

I have a similiar problem and came to the conclusion that your desired behaviour is unfortunately not possible after Firefox 60. However, bookmarklets work in the built-in PDF viewer. One possible fix would be to rewrite your userscript to work as a bookmarklet.

Here is a bug report indicating that the current behaviour is intentional: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1454760

Good luck!