# Autoprint script is not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to autoprint this [kind of page](https://polormb.sebina.it/sebina/getfile/sp/repo/reports/20230101/catalogazione/stpEtiColloc1672581119061_01.pdf?id=3873764) with an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk) using this script:

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf("/repo/reports")>0){
window.print()
}
```

The script is working on Chrome but not on Firefox, could you help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: Is this the complete script? How are you executing it? The link you've posted is a link to a generated PDF, and I can print it when I execute your code through Firefox's console.

Comment: I'm using [Autofill extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/autofill-quantum/)

Comment: Having never used that extension before, I'm afraid I can't really advise you much in that regard. I'm a [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) user myself. You might want to give that a try. In case you don't want to, you could try and edit your code to include a short timeout - for example `setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 100);`.

Comment: Unfortunally it doesn't work with the timeout. I don't know if I can adapt many rules I have to Tampermonkey. Thank you!

Comment: OK, let's try one more thing before giving up. Does anything show in the console if you replace `window.print()` with `console.log("123 ok!")` ? Also, be sure to enable all of the notifications inside the console - Erros, Logs, Info, Warning, Debug.

Comment: Yes, Firefox console correctly opens the print page (and of course  yes, giving console.log, correctly returns: '123 ok!'), but Autofill addon doesn't react. By the way, using TamperMonkey... Is this the right way? 

https://imgur.com/a/w206MMJ

as it doesn't work even with TamperMonkey...

Comment: It seems that it's not possible after all - at least not in this way. Please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767919/how-to-run-user-scripts-on-firefoxs-built-in-pdf-viewer) and the linked bugzilla ticket. You might be able to render your PDF so that it contains a script within itself, since [Firefox supports](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1333222) executing scripts which are inside a PDF document, but I'm not sure if that would be a good solution for you.

Comment: Okay, FiddlingAway, thanks for your time!